# What could plasma life look like?

Tags: creature-design, aliens, plasma, brown-dwarf

Let's say there was plasma life living in a brown dwarf. What shapes could we expect them to take? I'm not picky about what level of life, autotroph to sentient are of interest.

Comment: usually dodecahedrons

Comment: Where is the research Worldbuilding SE asked you for?

Even without research, where are your own ideas?

Comment: Dodecahedrons. I like that idea

Answer (score 1):

Plasma, being a collection of positive nuclei in a soup of free electrons, doesn't have a shape. It takes the shape of the confinement hosting it. I guess the same would still apply for a fictional life form based on plasma.

Then, because of the lack of a defined shape, we could speculate that, while the autotroph of these life forms would trive on  an external source of energy, the eterotroph would simply blend with their targets and absorb their energy, with the targets probably using some sort of on demand magnetic shielding to prevent the absorption. This on demand shielding might give them some sort of surface when activated.

Comment: Like Star Trek TOS *[Metamorphosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamorphosis_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series)),* but without the limitation of late-60s special effects.

Comment: Could large saucer shapes work?